# home directory expansion (~) within an argument

Tags: bash, expansion, tilde, home-directory

When I enter the following (BASH):

```
rdesktop -r disk:bacon=~/bacon host
```

It does not expand to

```
rdesktop -r disk:bacon=/home/me/bacon host
```

It seems the "disk:" part is the problem as can be seen in:

```
$ echo bacon=~/bacon disk:bacon=~/bacon

bacon=/home/me/bacon disk:bacon=~/bacon
```

How can I make tilde expand?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While ~ does not expand (it's used as specially routed of the path), `$HOME` does.

```
rdesktop -r disk:bacon=$HOME/bacon host
```

But be careful with environment-changing `su`!

Answer (score 6):

`rdesktop -r disk:bacon=$(echo ~/bacon) host`

will do it.  It won't please the eye, but it will work.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work? I've been reading the manual and have found only this *"Each variable assignment is checked for unquoted tilde-prefixes immediately following a : or the first =.  In these cases, tilde expansion is also performed. Consequently, one may use file names  with  tildes in assignments  to  PATH, MAILPATH, and CDPATH, and the shell assigns the expanded value."*

Comment: bash looks for tildes after ':' in the replacement string. 'disk:bacon=...' is not a valid variable assignment.

Comment: In particular, 'disk:bacon=...' isn't a variable assignment both because it isn't in a valid part of the command (variable assignments must come before the command name) and ':' isn't a valid character for a variable name.